# Inserting Data into Multiple rows from a text file php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web

What I'm trying to do is insert each line from a text file into a new row of a mysql database. What am I doing wrong?

I have a text file that looks something like the following.

```
11111,customer1
11112,customer2
11113,customer3
11114,customer4
```

My MySQL DB has the fields id, number, customer

My php code which isn't working looks like the following.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add File To DB</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="list.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />
<table>

<?php
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    // Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

    // Make an array using comma as delimiter
       $arrM = explode(',',fgets($f)); 
    // Write links (get the data in the array)
       echo '<tr><td name="number">' . $arrM[0] . '</td><td name="customer">' . $arrM[1] . '</td></tr>'; 

    }

    fclose($f);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';
$sql="INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('$_POST[number]','$_POST[customer]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your values are in the array `$arrM` not in `$_POST`. Please try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('$arrM[0]','$arrM[1]')";
```

Also you want to make sure you run this `$sql` in a loop.

Comment: `$arrM` won't be visible at the `$sql=` line

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code.If you want to just insert from the text file you can try the following

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add File To DB</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="list.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />
<table>

<?php
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    $arr_to_insert = array();
    // Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

    // Make an array using comma as delimiter
       $arrM = explode(',',fgets($f)); 
    // Write links (get the data in the array)
       echo '<tr><td name="number">' . $arrM[0] . '</td><td name="customer">' . $arrM[1] . '</td></tr>';
       //strore text file row to an array 
       $arr_to_insert[] = $arrM;
    }

    fclose($f);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';
foreach($arr_to_insert as $ai){
    $sql="INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('{$ai[0]}','{$ai[1]}')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
      }

}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The original version of your code with the problems commented.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add File To DB</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="list.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />
<table>

<?php
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    // you need to strore text file row to an array to later insert to database.
    // Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

    // Make an array using comma as delimiter
       $arrM = explode(',',fgets($f)); //$arrM is private inside while loop.
    // Write links (get the data in the array)
       echo '<tr><td name="number">' . $arrM[0] . '</td><td name="customer">' . $arrM[1] . '</td></tr>'; 

    }

    fclose($f);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';
//you are trying to insert $_POST[number] and $_POST[customer] which are non-existent
//also you need to loop through the rows in your text file and store each row.
$sql="INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('$_POST[number]','$_POST[customer]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</table>
<!-- duplicate submit button -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: Please note I am just pointing out the errors in your code and fixing as it is. I am not trying to optimize it. It looks like you are trying to learn PHP rather than get better solution.

Comment: Correct just learning. With the <input type="submit" value="Submit File" /> If I wanted one on the bottom and one at the top could I do that or would the to buttons conflict with each other?

Comment: You can have more than 1 submit. It won't conflict and both will work also.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your script.

1. First, you are using `$_POST['submit']` but haven't used `name='submit'` in your submit button.
2. As @vinod said your values are in the array `$arrM not in`$_POST`.

Now you need to insert your data in loop. Make sure you included your connection only once and close the connection after all database operation is complete.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add File To DB</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form action="list.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit File" /> <!-- Provide name `submit` to your button so that you can access $_POST['submit'] -->
  <table>

  <?php
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

    //include your connection around here so it is included only once
    include "connection.php";

    // Read line by line until end of file
    while (!feof($f)) { 

    // Make an array using comma as delimiter
       $arrM = explode(',',fgets($f)); 
    // Write links (get the data in the array)
       echo '<tr><td name="number">' . $arrM[0] . '</td><td name="customer">' . $arrM[1] . '</td></tr>'; 
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {               
            $sql = "INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('$arrM[0]','$arrM[0]')"; //here should be $arrM
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
            }               
        }
    }

    fclose($f);
    mysqli_close($con); //close your database connection here
  ?>
 </table>
 <!--<input type="submit" value="Submit File" />-->
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to insert data of the text file into the database then you can do this.
<?php   
include('dbcon.php');
$file_content=explode("\n",file_get_contents("demo.txt"));//write your text file name instead of demo.txt   
for($i=0;$i<count($file_content)-1;$i++){
    $exploded_content=explode(",",$file_content[$i]);
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"insert into demo (id,name) values('$exploded_content[0]','$exploded_content[1]')");
         //put your table name instead of demo it has two columns id and name
}

?>
Below is the dbcon.php file
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","dbname");
//put your host user pass database name above i put it dummy
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert value correctly

```
$sql="INSERT INTO list (number, customer) VALUES ('".$arrM[0]."','".$arrM[1]."')";
```